# NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.ContainerHelpers

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-support-library

I am working on an application. It works perfectly on a device with android 5.0. But crashes constantly on lower versions.
Have so far tried it out on 4.4.4, 4.4.2.

I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.ContainerHelpers
    at android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap.<init>(SimpleArrayMap.java:209)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getLoaderManager(FragmentActivity.java:867)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager(FragmentActivity.java:861)
    at com.client.login.LoginActivity.populateAutoComplete(LoginActivity.java:164)
    at com.client.login.LoginActivity.setupView(LoginActivity.java:126)
    at com.client.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:71)
```

I am using android studio for development. My build.gradle is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.client'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.5.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you configure proguard? (see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560244/proguard-error-when-exporting-signed-app-using-android-support-v4-app-honeycomb)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on this post

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB error when adding new module in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562172/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-app-navutilsjb-error-when-add)

Problem was due to multi dexing being added in lollipop. Had to add the multidex support library to my gradle for previous android versions.