# issue showing InterstitialAd in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am showing InterstitialAd in Android, when I run apk on Nexus 5 with version 6.0 the application runs smoothly and Ads are also displaying as expected.
But When I try to run the same apk on android TAB with version 4.4, the application get crashed.

From logcat

```
2-09 00:03:58.914: E/AndroidRuntime(12425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-09 00:03:58.914: E/AndroidRuntime(12425): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
```

Any Solution for that?

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/28767282/4848308

Comment: But its with android studio, can you guide me for eclipse?